# How to programmatically set an image in an UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I'm using this code to set an image in an UIImage view

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3092/2915896504_a88b69c9de.jpg"]]];
[self.ImageView setImage:image];      
NSLog(@"image set");
```

The log-statement is displayed in the console so the code is executed. I've made sure that an UIImageView is hooked up to self.ImageView

The image is not displayed in the UIImageView. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: firstly check your image which you are getting from NSData should not be NULL?

Comment: i'm getting the image:  NSLog(@"Image: %f %f\n", image.size.height, image.size.width);  correctly shows the dimensions of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sanity checking it:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3092/2915896504_a88b69c9de.jpg"]]];

assert(image && "error reading the image");

assert(self.ImageView && "there is no image view");

[self.ImageView setImage:image];      

NSLog(@"image set");
```

Comment: assert(self.ImageView && "there is no image view") fails. I've doublechecked that the UIImageView from the storyboard is hooked up to "@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;" in my headerfile and it is.

Comment: The code to set the image in the UIImageView is executed in prepareForSegue. Could it be that connected views of the destinationcontroller are not yet initialized at that moment?

Comment: @murze you *may* not be fully loaded at that point - a few breakpoints will prove the (current) order.

Comment: it seems that the views of the DestinationController are not entirely  when using prepareForSegue.